# Transpose rows into columns in another table using MS Access 2007

Tags: ms-access-2007

I need to transpose rows in to columns from table A to table B in MS Access 2007.

Here we go, Below is the data in Table01 which should be transposed to another table.

```
Customer_Name   Contacted_Date  Response_Code
Mr. Abc         01-Sep-12   Switched Off
Mr. Abc         02-Sep-12   Ringing
Mr. Abc         03-Sep-12   Call Back
Mr. Abc         04-Sep-12   Agreed
Mr. Def         01-Sep-12   Switched Off
Mr. Def         02-Sep-12   Ringing
Mr. Def         03-Sep-12   Call Back
Mr. Def         04-Sep-12   Agreed
Mrs. Ghi        01-Sep-12   Switched Off
Mrs. Ghi        02-Sep-12   Ringing
Mrs. Ghi        03-Sep-12   Call Back
Mrs. Ghi        04-Sep-12   Agreed
Mr. Jkl         01-Sep-12   Switched Off
Mr. Jkl         02-Sep-12   Ringing
Mr. Jkl         03-Sep-12   Call Back
Mr. Jkl         04-Sep-12   Agreed
Mr. Mno         01-Sep-12   Switched Off
Mr. Mno         02-Sep-12   Ringing
Mr. Mno         03-Sep-12   Call Back
Mr. Mno         04-Sep-12   Agreed
Mrs. Pqr        01-Sep-12   Switched Off
Mrs. Pqr        02-Sep-12   Ringing
Mrs. Pqr        03-Sep-12   Call Back
Mrs. Pqr        04-Sep-12   Agreed
```

Here is the exact thing what i need.

```
Customer_Name   01-Sep-12   02-Sep-12   03-Sep-12   04-Sep-12
Mr. Abc         Switched Off    Ringing         Call Back   Agreed
Mr. Def         Switched Off    Ringing         Call Back   Agreed
Mrs. Ghi        Switched Off    Ringing         Call Back   Agreed
Mr. Jkl         Switched Off    Ringing         Call Back   Agreed
Mr. Mno         Switched Off    Ringing         Call Back   Agreed
Mrs. Pq         Switched Off    Ringing         Call Back   Agreed
```

So, the data is transposed in to a separate table called as Table02.

Comment: Use the query design window or the wizards to build a crosstab query.

Comment: If a cross tab query is also built, the values will come only in numbers were in i need to have the data as below to be delivered Customer_Name   01-Sep-12   02-Sep-12   03-Sep-12   04-Sep-12
Mr. Abc         Switched Off    Ringing         Call Back   Agreed
Mr. Def         Switched Off    Ringing         Call Back   Agreed
Mrs. Ghi        Switched Off    Ringing         Call Back   Agreed
Mr. Jkl         Switched Off    Ringing         Call Back   Agreed
Mr. Mno         Switched Off    Ringing         Call Back   Agreed
Mrs. Pq         Switched Off    Ringing         Call Back   Agreed.

Comment: You can use First, Last, Min and Max to get names etc.

Comment: I'm not that much good in Access. Can you send me the snapshot on how it can be done??