# Converting Rows to Columns in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a list of 750 sections of classes in Access and then the counts of the number of students that are in the class by section. It looks like this where 1 am refers to week 1 of the camp and am is the morning session and pm is the afternoon session.

```
Name                Count
Babysitting - 1am     5
Babysitting - 1PM     7
Arts & Crafts - 1am   9
Arts & Crafts - 1am   6
...
```

I need it to be structured by session though per class. Like this:

```
Name          Week1am    Week1PM
Babysitting      5         7
Arts & Crafts    9         6
```

I have the week and time codes as separate fields in the class table, but I needed them to display in the name of each class in the class table for another reason. I know how to get the last 5 characters off the name for this query though. I used: `Left ([Name], Len([Name])-5)`. However, I'm not sure if after I do that if it's possible to use a group by query to get to the final output I'm looking for at that point.

If anyone can help I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Use transpose mechanism 

 

   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12602858/transpose-rows-into-columns-in-another-table-using-ms-access-2007

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210512/transpose-a-table-using-query-in-access

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736317/sql-to-transpose-row-pairs-to-columns-in-ms-access-database

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic application of pivot tables in Access.

If you already have your "Name" column splitted in `Name` and `Time` columns (by using `Left()` and `Len()`) functions, you can transform this easily in a pivot table:

```
transform sum([count]) as totalCount
select [name]
from [yourTableOrQuery]
group by [name]
pivot [time]
```

Check the online help for `transform` (I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208956%28v=office.12%29.aspx), but maybe the online help of Access can provide you with a better explanation).

Hope this helps you.